# PHP dropdown not sending through POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have drop downs built by a PHP function pulling from MySQL tables. The drop downs work fine but the selected option isn't POSTing.  I suspect the problem is with how the HTML select tag is created in PHP but I can't seem to find a way to correct it.  I've searched around but nothing seems to work.

Here is the PHP function to build the drop down:

```
function contact_list(){
//Connection info
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$db = 'database';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'password';

//Define connection
$con = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db);

//Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo " ERROR " . mysqli_connect_error() . " ERROR ";
        }  
 //Define search strings for drop down       
 $contact_list = "SELECT * FROM CONTACT_LIST";       

//Execute search of primary_contact table
if (!mysqli_query($con,$contact_list)) {
    die('' . mysqli_error($con));
}
//Return primary_contact results as string
$contact_result = $con->query($contact_list);

//Build drop down
echo "<select name='Primary_Contact'>";
//Loop through results
foreach ($contact_result as $row)
{
    echo "<option value='' >" .htmlspecialchars($row['Primary_Contact']). "</option>";
}

echo "</select><p></p>";
}
```

Here is a sample of the HTML.  The Description text box is fine so I don't think the problem is with the form tags.

```
<form action="mod_output_test.php" method="POST">  
    <u>Description</u>:  <p></p>
    <input type="text" name="Description" size="48" value="<?=$Description;?>"> <p></p>
    <!-- Primary Contact -->
    <?php echo "<u>Primary Contact</u>:<p></p>Current value:&nbsp<b> " . $Primary_Contact . "</b>&nbsp New value: ";?>
    <?php contact_list() ?>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What is the actual html output?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is there is no `<form>` tag, but since you didn't post the HTML, I could be wrong.

Comment: Edited to include <form> along with a text field that does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
echo "<option value='' >" .htmlspecialchars($row['Primary_Contact']). "</option>";
```

to

```
echo "<option value='".$row['Id']."'>" .htmlspecialchars($row['Primary_Contact']). "</option>";
```

And I am guessing your dropdows is between a form tag.

in the top of the action file type this and tell us what you get

```
<?php
print_r($_REQUEST);
exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<option value='' >" .htmlspecialchars($row['Primary_Contact']). "</option>";
```

When you post like that, option value is empty. Add the id of the contact.

As they said, we see no `<form>` tag, we "assume" you add it before that piece. But the answer to "is not posting" is because value from `<option>` is empty.

Comment: Edited to include <form> along with a text field that does work.

Comment: Good, make sure also to add the value to the `<option>` tag also. If not, no value will have the variable when posting